# UnityからAmazon S3にファイルをアップロードして公開状態にしたい

Tags: unity3d, amazon-s3, unity2d

[マルチポスト](https://teratail.com/questions/113303)

[UnityからAmazon S3にファイルをアップロードし、公開状態にする](https://qiita.com/arumani/items/a0fd345dd224fb5d05db)

上記の記事を参考に同じことをしようとしていますが，S3の処理で失敗します。
どうすればうまくいくでしょうか？

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentity;

public class TestS3 : MonoBehaviour {

    // 以下AWSのテンプレ
    void Start () {
        UnityInitializer.AttachToGameObject(this.gameObject);
        AWSConfigs.HttpClient = AWSConfigs.HttpClientOption.UnityWebRequest;
        CognitoAWSCredentials credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials (
            "ID プールの ID", // ID プールの ID
            RegionEndpoint.APNortheast1 // リージョン
        );

        // S3の設定とアップ
        AmazonS3Client S3Client = new AmazonS3Client (credentials, RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(RegionEndpoint.APNortheast1.SystemName));     
        string S3BucketName = "バケット名";
        string fileName = "アップしたいファイル名";

        var stream = new FileStream(Application.streamingAssetsPath +
            Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + fileName,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

        Debug.Log(Application.streamingAssetsPath +
            Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + fileName);
        var request = new PostObjectRequest()
        {
            Bucket = S3BucketName,
            Key = fileName,
            InputStream = stream,
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead // 公開状態
        };

        S3Client.PostObjectAsync(request, (responseObj) =>
            {
                if (responseObj.Exception == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("success");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("fail");// ←これになる
                }
            });     
    }   
}
```

特にわからなかったとこがIAMの設定で，
・ロールポリシーの作成 をクリック
・Policy Generator の枠内にある 選択 をクリック
とうがどこを押せばいいのかわかりませんでしたので以下のように設定しました。

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/332
に書かれているようにRegionを明記すれば成功した。具体的には以下

```
var request = new PostObjectRequest()
{
    Bucket = S3BucketName,
    Key = fileName,
    InputStream = stream,
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead, // 公開状態
    Region = RegionEndpoint.APNortheast1 // ←これを追加！！！！      
};
```